# How do i deep link into a specific screen within an iOS app (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, deep-linking, custom-url

My Swift iOS application contains two screens.

1. Home Page (HomePageViewController)
2. Start Page (StartPageViewController). A button click on Home Page takes user to this page. This page has a Cancel button, that would take user back to Home Page.

My requirement is to deep link to StartPageViewController.

I have this piece of code in AppDelegate -

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        if(url.path == "/startPage"){

            let startPage: StartPageViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartPageViewController") as! StartPageViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = startPage
         }
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()        
        return true
    }
```

With this code, deep link takes user to Start Page. But, on clicking Cancel button, a white screen appears rather than going back to home page. (which i think is because start page is the rootViewController).

How do I direct user to Start Page and go back to Home page on clicking Cancel.

Thanks!

Comment: Pls explain flow of vc bcz I unable to understand. Sry.

Comment: @dahiya_boy - Deep link should take user to Start Page. Clicking Cancel button on start page should take user to Home Page. Right now, with the code i pasted above, Deep link takes user to Start Page, but on clicking cancel button, A white screen appears. (user is not taken back to Home Page. need to make this work).

Comment: Pls correct me of I am wrg. Your app starts with startpageVC and on cancel click app moves to HomeVc and never comes to startpageVC.

Comment: If you don't want to come back on StartPage then set HomeVC as rootVC as you done above otherwise you need to use pushVC concept.

Answer (score -1):

When deep linking, you'll have to go through the same path you would as a user.

So, first make HomePageViewController as rootViewController and present StartPageViewController onto that programmatically.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if(url.path == "/startPage") {
        let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController") as! HomePageViewController
        homePage.buttonClick(nil) // Make sure the action receive optional sender object 

        self.window?.rootViewController = homePage
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()        
    return true
}
```

Try this out and let me know how it went ^_^

Comment: I have tested this implementation and verified that it works, check if this suit your needs.

Comment: Wrong concept. Bcz with this User Nevers comes to PageVC.

Comment: if you don't have the NavigationController model then assign homePage directly to self.window?.rootViewController.

Comment: @dahiya_boy, the buttonActionMethod will redirect user form homePage to startPageVC. The buttonActionMethod here should obviously be replaced by whatever method name OP has given to his button action.

Comment: I think I confused you guys :( 
It's a simple two screen app and this is how it works - App opens on Home Page. There is a button on Home Page that would take user to another page called Start Page. Start Page has a cancel button to take user back to home page.
Now I want a deep link concept to be implemented. the requirement is using deep link feature, user should be taken to Start Page rather than home page. So, if user want to go to home from start page, cancel button should serve it's purpose. With my code written above, cancel button on start page leaves user with a blank white screen.

Comment: are you using navigation controller?, what is the method name of the button action?

Either case the above code should work just fine :)

Comment: cancel button dismisses the page. 
`dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: cool, i'll edit the code in a moment, and can you also let me know the method name you use in HomePageViewController to get StartPage?

Comment: `@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton)`

Comment: change it to @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton?), and use my code above

Comment: @iNishinKareem, Please let me know if it doesn't work and please accept the answer if it works, thanks. :)